# Use Node.js as workaround for Cors

Tags: node.js, express, cors

Using Nodejs and Express 4, I am trying to do a post on 
my express server which in turn will take inputs from browser 
and do a post on external server as a CORS workaround.

This the route to my server:

```
app.post('/api',            api.postme);
```

This is my api.js file.

```
 exports.postme = function (req, res, next) {

    res.send("hello Apis");
};
```

For Example an external server:

```
https://website/NoJSONPHere/

params: page=1, query="frogs"
```

Is it possible to do this??

Comment: Close this?? really.. there isnt a single blog that addresses this use of node.

Comment: There are Node libraries that will handle proxying for you: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: SO frowns on questions that show no attempt to solve the problem.  Give it a shot and come back when you get stuck.

Comment: I solved it...use a proxy server within my server. SO weakness is people on SO think OP knows the scope of the question being asked. They may not know. Now, I know I will solve it. Links to URL dont solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a second node server, host it somewhere in the cloud. 
Then have mobile (blocked) app make calls against your server.

So, 
your app> your server > their server.

Avoids,
your app > their server.

The reason this works is server to server connections or not blocked. 
Browser to server is sometimes blocked.